how to remove log in page for custom app?
I created one custom app When I submit data through this app, it displays a login page I would like to remove. How can I achieve this?
(https://i.sstatic.net/emi2ryvI.png)
I'm trying to navigate to another page redirection but it's not working.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

For this, I have found a solution.
